# Compile kernel with specific config

Tags: kernel

I am on ubuntu and would like to compile a kernel + Con Kolivas patch for my netbook (with lubuntu) .

The problem is my netbook is 32 bit and my ubuntu pc is 64 bit.

If I take the .config from the netbook, throw it into the kernel folder (with patch already applied) and try to compile it. It takes the config from the normal ubuntu pc (i am compiling on)  and asks me additional questions.

I hope you can help :)

Comment: cross compiling is not easy, I suggest you build on the 32 bit netbook. It ill take longer, but it is easier. If you insist on building on the 64 bit machine, either install a 32 bit version to build on or google search cross compiling

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Unfortunately my netbook crashes if I try to do that...

Comment: see the link I gave you for options.